# MongoDB - Subtract two dates and return value in seconds

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Scenario:**

I am trying to subtract two dates in MongoDB and return the time it took to process the event by whatever Id I provided.
I was able to get the following results (code#1) from the mongo search using query#1.

query#1 Returns for all the values in the database am looking to get only for two ids

I am trying to keep the below IN query(query#2) in the query#1 or anything relevant, but no luck any help would be really helpful

Code#1:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "receivedTime" : ISODate("2021-08-10T17:56:56.305Z"),
    "deliveryTime" : ISODate("2021-08-10T17:56:59.941Z"),
    "processedTime" : 3.636
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "234",
    "receivedTime" : ISODate("2021-08-10T17:57:00.223Z"),
    "deliveryTime" : ISODate("2021-08-10T17:57:00.691Z"),
    "processedTime" : 0.468
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "345",
    "receivedTime" : ISODate("2021-08-10T17:57:19.812Z"),
    "deliveryTime" : ISODate("2021-08-10T17:57:20.331Z"),
    "processedTime" : 0.519
}
```

query #1:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "receivedTime": 1,
            "deliveryTime": 1,
            "processedTime": {
                "$divide": [
                    {
                        "$subtract": [
                            "$deliveryTime",
                            "$receivedTime"
                        ]
                    },
                    1000 //1000 for sec, 60000 for minute, 3600000 for hour
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

query#2:

```
db.mycollection.find({
    "_id": {
        $in: [
            "123",
            "234"
        ]
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage as the first stage to filter the documents by `_id`.
Next, proceed to `$project` stage for returning the desired format for the documents.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": {
        $in: [
          "123",
          "234"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "receivedTime": 1,
      "deliveryTime": 1,
      "processedTime": {
        "$divide": [
          {
            "$subtract": [
              "$deliveryTime",
              "$receivedTime"
            ]
          },
          1000//1000 for sec, 60000 for minute, 3600000 for hour
          
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QybMvaZnMH-)

Comment: Hi @Mallikarjun, you are welcome. Can you accept this answer as it helps? Thank you.